# Included CDI-enabled Servlet Fails with ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303:

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cdi, weld

I am writing a CDI application that runs on Tomcat. I am using Tomcat 7.0.62 with
Weld 2.2.12.Final as the CDI implementation. I am using CDI without JSF.

The application consists of a dispatcher servlet that is not CDI enabled. The
dispatcher includes the output of a CDI enabled servlet to create the page.

When the dispatcher servlet and the CDI servlet are both in the same web app, 
it works fine. However, I need the CDI servlet to be in a different web app, so
I do a cross-context include. When I do the cross-context include, the CDI servlet 
produces output until it attempts to access an @RequestScoped bean. Bean 
access fails with the following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
...
```

I have tried activating CDI for the dispatcher servlet as well, but it doesn't 
seem to make any difference.

It looks to me like the request context for the CDI servlet is not being set up
properly when the CDI servlet is included as opposed to receiving the request 
directly.

I have searched this site and also through Google, but have not found a matching
problem / solution. I found a tomcat context setting 'fireRequestListenersOnForwards="true"'
that I applied to the dispatcher servlet, but that did not make a difference.

Is this a configuration problem? Could anyone provide a clue about how to solve this?

I would be very grateful!

---

**Background information:**

The actual application having the problem is large, so I condensed it down to get 
to the essence of brokenness. As a result, I have two war files. The first war file
contains the CDI servlet and the dispatcher (in code I called it the includer) servlet. The second war file contains only
the dispatcher servlet.

**The CDI Servlet**

The CDI Servlet has a context.xml file in its META_INF directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

The CDI servlet web.xml file contains the lines:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>

<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

The CDI Servlet WEB-INF directory contains a beans.xml file.

The CDI servlet bootstraps bean execution through use of a BeanManager obtained 
through JNDI lookup (this is working):

```
BeanManager bm = null;
try {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

    try {
       // "regular" naming
       bm = (BeanManager) context.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch(NameNotFoundException e) {
       // try again with Tomcat naming
       bm = (BeanManager) context.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}

if (bm == null) {
   writer.write("Couldn't look up the bean manager");
} else {
   Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(EnclosingBean.class);
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   Bean<EnclosingBean> bean = (Bean<EnclosingBean>) bm.resolve(beans);
   if (bean == null) {
      writer.write("Couldn't get the bean");
   } else {
      EnclosingBean eb = (EnclosingBean) bm.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), bm.createCreationalContext(bean));
      writer.write("finally here we are. Name is: ");
      writer.write(eb.getName());
   }
}
```

**The Includer (Dispatcher) Servlet**

The includer servlet has a context.xml file in its META-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context 
   path="/ExternalIncluderServlet" 
   docBase="ExternalIncluderServlet.war" 
   crossContext="true" 
   fireRequestListenersOnForwards="true">

    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

The includer servlet looks up the context of the CDI servlet and obtains a 
RequestDispatcher as follows (this works):

```
ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();
ServletContext extsc = sc.getContext("/SimpleCDIServlet");
if (extsc == null) {
   writer.println("<p>Couldn't get the external context.</p>");
} else {

   RequestDispatcher rd = extsc.getRequestDispatcher("/CDIServlet");
   if (rd == null) {
        writer.println("<p>RequestDispatcher is null.</p>");
   } else {
       writer.println("<p>Got the RequestDispatcher.</p>");
       rd.include(req, resp);
   }
}
```

**Results:**

When I use the browser to access the CDI servlet directly via the URI: localhost:8080/SimpleCDIServlet/CDIServlet I get the expected output:

```
Simple CDI Servlet
finally here we are. Name is: InjectedBean
```

If I access the CDI servlet through a dispatcher servlet located in the same web app as the CDI servlet, it works as well. URI: /SimpleCDIServlet/IncluderServlet, output:

```
Simple CDI Servlet Including Servlet
Will now include the CDI servlet ...
Got the RequestDispatcher.
Simple CDI Servlet
finally here we are. Name is: InjectedBean
```

But if I include the CDI servlet from a different context, I don't get the injected bean name in the output and the exception noted above is in the log. URI: /ExternalIncluderServlet/IncluderServlet, Output:

```
CDI Servlet Includer

This servlet includes a CDI servlet in a different web app. It is not CDI enabled.

Got the RequestDispatcher.
Simple CDI Servlet
finally here we are. Name is:
```

Note that I can't use a request dispatcher forward instead of include as the original
application includes output from several other servlets, not just one. And opening
a new HTTP request for each include would be inefficient, since the number of requests
would be multiplied by the number of included servlets, and it would be fairly ugly
on top of that.

---

**Update:**
I tried this out on Tomee 1.7.2 and also on WebSphere Application Server v8.5. The results are summarized below.

```
                           WAS 8.5           Tomcat 7.0.62           Tomee 1.7.2
                           =======           =============           ===========
CDI servlet direct access   works               works                   works

Included by servlet         works               works                   works          
   in same web app

Included by servlet         works               broken                  broken 
   in different web app
```

---

The more I think about this, the more I feel that it really should work. You should be able to
successfully use a request dispatcher to include output from a CDI-enabled servlet on Tomcat.
I hope that someone here can help me figure out how to make it work.

Comment: And what's on the ...  ? How do you actually obtain the content generated by your CDIServlet? Secondly: can you invoke the servlet directly from a browser (or a HttpRequester tool) rather than through the front-controller? Does that work successfully?

Comment: Hi Gimby, Thanks for your response. I expanded on the code fragment and also added program output text. If I access the CDI servlet directly, it works. It also works if I access the CDI servlet through a dispatcher servlet located in the same web app as the CDI portlet. It fails When I try to include the servlet from a different context.

Comment: Good question. In essence CDI/Weld doesn't get the chance to initialize itself when a cross-context include is done. This does not actually strike me as something odd since there will be no actual HTTP request involved to the CDIServlet in such a case so that CDI listener may not even be firing. Technical workaround: do a HTTP request to the second servlet, but I'm wondering if there is a proper solution for this.

Comment: That's what I think, too - it looks like CDI isn't initializing itself, possibly because the CDI listener isn't firing. Interestingly, there is a special Tomcat context flag for something similar to this:

"fireRequestListenersOnForwards: 
Set to true to fire any configured ServletRequestListeners when Tomcat forwards a request. This is primarily of use to users of CDI frameworks that use ServletRequestListeners to configure the necessary environment for a request. If not specified, the default value of false is used."
I set it on the dispatcher servlet, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.  Can you explain what contents are in each of the WAR files you deploy? Why do you need to have two different war files?

Comment: John, I edited the post again to hopefully make it more clear. I have two war files because that is the minimum needed to reproduce the problem I am having with a much larger application consisting of a number of war files.

Comment: @ScottNicklous that is an interesting parameter which is designed to work on only a -forward-. That makes me wonder if a forward isn't what you should be doing here, rather than an include.

Comment: Hi Gimby, I can't use a request dispatcher forward, as my application aggregates the output from several servlets, some of which may be CDI servlets.  Also, I did a little more testing. The application works correctly on IBM WebSphere Application Server (using the native WAS CDI support rather than Weld), which makes me inclined to believe that I am dealing with either a Tomcat or a Weld limitation.

Comment: Download Apache TomEE (tomcat + OpenWebBeans as the CDI implementation/container), and post any/all questions on the tomee user list, and they 'will' help you solve the issue by using TomEE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WOW! with the help of a good friend, I got it!

To make this work, you need to configure a special Weld cross-context filter. You configure the filter by adding the following lines to the web.xml file.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>WeldCrossContextFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldCrossContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>WeldCrossContextFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I configure this, a cross-context include of a CDI servlet works as expected.
I tried it out on Tomcat 7.0.42 and 8.0.23 and so far, so good.

See also:

http://javadox.com/org.jboss.weld/weld-core-impl/2.2.4.Final/org/jboss/weld/servlet/WeldCrossContextFilter.html

I looked for a reference to the filter in the official Weld documentation, but was unable
to locate anything. Anyway, I hope this might help someone.